# Change of the edited cell in a datagridview cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with cells containing strings. If a cell content is changed, I want to change the `background` of this cell. What event is the best for doing this?

I first tried the `CellValueChanged` event, but this is even called by clicking this cell without editing the content.

Here is my function code:

```
private void GVCrs_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     this.GVCrs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
}
```

Regards
R4z0R

Comment: Can you post the code you tried in CellValueChanged event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `CellBeginEdit` and `CellEndEdit` events,

```
string beforeValue = "";
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
     beforeValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
}

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() != beforeValue)
     {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            beforeValue = "";
     }
}
```

**Result;**
[image]
Hope helps,